# system.runtime.serialization.serializationException was thrown

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I want to run following delegate in my **xamarin android** project.

But after running this ,an object `S` of State class contains `null`.
And this error points to the following line in code.

```
tv.Text = s.name+""+s.population;
```

`tv` is a `textview` in my code.

```
button.Click += async delegate {

    state s = new state();
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    string url = "http://iforindia.azurewebsites.net/api/state/uid/33F8A8D5-0DF2-47A0-9C79-002351A95F88";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
    if (response.ReasonPhrase.Contains("OK"))
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(state));
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            s= (state)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }
    else if (response.ReasonPhrase.Contains("Bad Request"))
    {
        s= null;
    }
    else
    {
        s= null;
    }
    tv.Text = s.name+""+s.population;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is redundant (response.ReasonPhase would have already raised a null exception):

```
if (response != null)
```

Try this:

```
 button.Click += async delegate {

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var url = "http://iforindia.azurewebsites.net/api/state/uid/33F8A8D5-0DF2-47A0-9C79-002351A95F88";
    var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
    if (response != null && response.ReasonPhrase.Contains("OK"))
    {
            var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(state));
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var s = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream) as state;

            if (s != null)
            {
                 tv.Text = s.name+""+s.population;
            }   
        }
   };
```